# Scrollable and Endless map - libgdx

Tags: dictionary, libgdx, repeat

I want to create a simple game with a space ship that needs to dodge asteroids and stuff along the way.

Now, I can think of several ways to spawn the obstacles in the map. My only problem is, how do I implement the idea of an endless map/scrollable map?

For instance, in Flappy Bird there is an endless map.

I just want to know what is the best approach to implement this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alon said, for the background you can use several horizontally "tileable" textures, just load them behind the current one when it's edge is almost visible. You can actually make multiple layers to create depth, for instance you can create a foreground layer with some clouds/nebula's the player travels behind, then some space dust behind the player traveling slower and some planets traveling very slowly in the distance.

Simply create a array for each layer of tileable background textures. Make these textures a bit (or a lot) wider then the actual screen. Keep adding textures to the right side, pick them randomly from your array, and let them scroll. Of course you delete textures when they traversed the screen and not shown anymore.

For your objects you just spawn the asteroids off screen and let them travel across the screen. You maintain a asteroid list and each time you need an asteroid you generate it with a random Y axis and add it to the list. When you need to draw or calculate collision you traverse this list and do your stuff on each asteroid.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I recommend this one:

Move your character in needed direction and respawn obstacles on global position. Camera should follow the character. For moving background you have two options: [ParallaxBackground](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795) which already knows how to move backgrounds or you can just create two backgrounds and when character will be in the end of first one you will move second background to the end.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you please elaborate a little bit about ParalllaxBackground and Camera's focus?

Comment: ParalllaxBackground - is class which can move backgrounds with se speed. You can read more on it's description (link in answer). Camera's focus - You will need to change position of camera every frame to make if focused on player. Small example: camera.position.set(hero.position.x, hero.position.y, 0);